# How do I use python to correctly format the time it took to complete an exercise?

Tags: python, pandas, time

In one dataset, I have time elapsed rows that are written as 32:43:00, meaning 32 minutes 42 seconds and time elapsed rows that are written as 1:00:10 or 1:07:41, meaning 1 hour 0 minutes and 10 seconds or 1 hour 7 minutes and 41 seconds. As of now when I import this data the data type for the times is an object but if I try to convert the data to time and format as %hh:%mm:%ss I get an error. How can I use python to correctly read in that 32:43 is 32 minutes and 43 seconds not 32 hours and 43 minutes?

In excel the row appears as 32:42:00 but in the fx it shows as 1/1/1900 8:59:00 AM

this is what I have tried so far

```
# convert the racetime column to timedelta format
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

# calculate the total seconds for each timedelta value
total_seconds = df['Time'].dt.total_seconds()

# create a timedelta column from the total seconds
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(total_seconds, unit='s')

# format the time column as hh:mm:ss
df['Time'] = df['RaceTime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df)type here
```

Comment: _time elapsed rows that are written as 32:43:00_ What is the datatype?  Is that a string?  Or an actual time interval type?

Answer (score 0):

#### You can control the formatting like this:

`divmod` is a useful function for this sort of task, returning both the integer result of the division *and* each time the remainder, which you need for the subsequent step.

```
hours, remainder = divmod(total_seconds, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
return f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use python to correctly read in that 32:43 is 32 minutes and 43 seconds not 32 hours and 43 minutes?

Divide the timedelta by 60.

```
>>> print(pd.to_timedelta('32:42:00')/60)
0 days 00:32:42
>>> (pd.to_timedelta('32:42:00')/60).components    
Components(days=0, hours=0, minutes=32, seconds=42, milliseconds=0, microseconds=0, nanoseconds=0)
>>>
```